# JQUERY dialog box with form

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, dialog, popup

my Jquery dialog box is not hidden. when the page is loaded it is automatically called and displayed while I set its property to autopen to false. I set a button to click event to open the dialog box. but in no vain

my code for Jquery is here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                buttons: [{ text: "OK", click: function () { $(this).dialog("close") } }],
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false
            });
            $('#btnpopup').click(function () {
                $('#dialog').dialog("open");
            });
```

My code for HTML

```
<div >
            <asp:Button ID="btnpopup" runat="server" Text="Add Instruction" />
        </div>
        <div id="dialog">
             <table>
           <tr>
               <td>Title</td>
               <td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="titlefield" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

               </td>
                <td>Instruction Category</td>
               <td>
                   <select id="category"></select>

               </td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
              <FTB:FreeTextBox ID="FreeTextBox1" runat="server"></FTB:FreeTextBox>
          </tr>
                         
                
       </table>
        </div>
```

Included Libraries

```
e<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js" ></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery.layout-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/jquery.ui.layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>nter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you loading jquery ui library twice, so it conflicted. Just use it only once after your jquery library has been load. Please see below reference.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery.layout-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/jquery.ui.layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which should I place libraries and which should be skipped, kindly help

Comment: I have given your above list please just copy and pase it.

Comment: These seem like mine.

Comment: Please check and compare you have added Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js at top of library, which I have removed.

Comment: I updated with these libraries but still the same result. Now there is shown a dialog but it vanishes in meanwhile

Comment: Then just add <div id="dialog" style="display:none;"> ie. hide the dialog in your case. It will be work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to put a last curly bracket and a bracket **})**
it works on mine
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1Va.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            buttons: [{
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                }
            }],
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $('#btnpopup').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");
        });
    })
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/siannas/pen/XWRKPmY)